# AzureML link to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it a way in order to link the run id with the blob storage? I know how to find the information for each step, which are stored in `default blob > azureml > ExperimentRun > dcid.stepId` but don't find a way to find the output of the job as well in the blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default storage mechanism according to the UI in azure ML is blob storage. The output will be available in metrics folder in the container

Checkout the screens below

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Download the JSON which contains the output information.

[image]